# Json String parsing in android

Tags: android

I have these joke in String through Async task and Json Help but when i try to parse them using  xyz = xxx.split(",");    it only show some text sentence only.
I need to get the all joke which are between joke:"chuck Norris...."
How to get all string between "".

```
    {
"type":"success",
"value":[
    {
        "id":484,
        "joke":"Chuck Norris is actually the front man for Apple. He let's Steve Jobs run the show when he's on a mission. Chuck Norris is always on a mission.",
        "categories":[

        ]
    },
    {
        "id":108,
        "joke":"The show Survivor had the original premise of putting people on an island with Chuck Norris. There were no survivors, and nobody is brave enough to go to the island to retrieve the footage.",
        "categories":[

        ]
    },
    {
        "id":127,
        "joke":"Chuck Norris invented the bolt-action rifle, liquor, sexual intercourse, and football-- in that order.",
        "categories":[

        ]
    },
    {
        "id":396,
        "joke":"Only Chuck Norris can prevent forest fires.",
        "categories":[

        ]
    },
    {
        "id":140,
        "joke":"Chuck Norris built a better mousetrap, but the world was too frightened to beat a path to his door.",
        "categories":[

        ]
    },
    {
        "id":164,
        "joke":"Chuck Norris once sued Burger King after they refused to put razor wire in his Whopper Jr, insisting that that actually is &quot;his&quot; way.",
        "categories":[

        ]
    },
    {
        "id":74,
        "joke":"In honor of Chuck Norris, all McDonald's in Texas have an even larger size than the super-size. When ordering, just ask to be Chucksized.",
        "categories":[

        ]
    },
    {
        "id":599,
        "joke":"Chuck Norris can make fire using two ice cubes.",
        "categories":[

        ]
    },
    {
        "id":416,
        "joke":"Chuck Norris plays racquetball with a waffle iron and a bowling ball.",
        "categories":[

        ]
    },
    {
        "id":69,
        "joke":"Scientists have estimated that the energy given off during the Big Bang is roughly equal to 1CNRhK (Chuck Norris Roundhouse Kick).",
        "categories":[
            "nerdy"
        ]
    }
]
}
```

public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {

```
public String[] xyz;
RecyclerView rv;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    new http().execute();

}




@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

   final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);



    //RecyclerView rv;
    rv = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rv_recycler_view);
    rv.setHasFixedSize(true);



    //MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(xyz);

   // rv.setAdapter(adapter);

    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    rv.setLayoutManager(llm);

    return rootView;
}




    class http extends AsyncTask<URL, String, String> {


        public String xxx="";

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(URL... urls) {
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;


            BufferedReader reader = null;
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random/10?escape=HTML");

                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();

                InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                 String line = "";
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                    buffer.append(line);
                }
                String finalJson = buffer.toString();
                JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(finalJson);
                JSONArray parentArray = parentObject.getJSONArray("value");
                for (int i = 0; i < parentArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    String name = jsonObject.getString("joke");
                    xxx += name ;


                }
                return xxx;


            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (connection != null) {
                    connection.disconnect();
                }
                try {
                    if (reader != null) {
                        reader.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            xyz = xxx.split("\"\"");

            MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(xyz);

            rv.setAdapter(adapter);

        }`enter code here`
    }
}
```

Comment: would be a lot better if you pretty print the json

Comment: Can you post the entire code you are using to parse ?

Answer (score 0):

This JSON should be stored in a JSONObject so you can get all the data from the fields. If the JSON of your example is in a JSONObject called "example" you should get the first joke as the following:

`example.value[0].joke;`

This would have: "Chuck Norris is actually the front man for Apple. He let's Steve Jobs run the show when he's on a mission. Chuck Norris is always on a mission."

Take into account that value is a JSONArray so you can loop it for get all jokes.

Answer (score 0):

Do not parse the json manually ! use `JSONObject` and `JSONArray` :

```
List<String> jokes = new ArrayList<>();
String json = "{ \"type\": \"success\", \"value\": [ { \"id\": 484, \"joke\": \"Chuck Norris is actually the front man for Apple. He let's Steve Jobs run the show when he's on a mission. Chuck Norris is always on a mission.\", \"categories\": [] }, { \"id\": 108, \"joke\": \"The show Survivor had the original premise of putting people on an island with Chuck Norris. There were no survivors, and nobody is brave enough to go to the island to retrieve the footage.\", \"categories\": [] }, { \"id\": 127, \"joke\": \"Chuck Norris invented the bolt-action rifle, liquor, sexual intercourse, and football-- in that order.\", \"categories\": [] }, { \"id\": 396, \"joke\": \"Only Chuck Norris can prevent forest fires.\", \"categories\": [] }, { \"id\": 140, \"joke\": \"Chuck Norris built a better mousetrap, but the world was too frightened to beat a path to his door.\", \"categories\": [] }, { \"id\": 164, \"joke\": \"Chuck Norris once sued Burger King after they refused to put razor wire in his Whopper Jr, insisting that that actually is &quot;his&quot; way.\", \"categories\": [] }, { \"id\": 74, \"joke\": \"In honor of Chuck Norris, all McDonald's in Texas have an even larger size than the super-size. When ordering, just ask to be Chucksized.\", \"categories\": [] }, { \"id\": 599, \"joke\": \"Chuck Norris can make fire using two ice cubes.\", \"categories\": [] }, { \"id\": 416, \"joke\": \"Chuck Norris plays racquetball with a waffle iron and a bowling ball.\", \"categories\": [] }, { \"id\": 69, \"joke\": \"Scientists have estimated that the energy given off during the Big Bang is roughly equal to 1CNRhK (Chuck Norris Roundhouse Kick).\", \"categories\": [\"nerdy\"] } ]  }\n";
try {
    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(json);
    JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray("value");
    for(int i=0 ; i<array.length() ; i++){
        JSONObject joke = array.getJSONObject(i);
        jokes.add(joke.getString("joke"));
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(jokes.toArray(new String[jokes.size()]));
```

Comment: i am using API which is generating 10 random jokes every time

Comment: so what ? You said **_I need to get the all joke_**

Comment: I need to get all jokes which i am getting but i have to split joke into card view, All jokes are randomly generated at http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random/10

Comment: i need to display one joke in one card view and another in another one and so on

Comment: That wasn't the original question... Anyway, you could create a fragment to display a joke, then make a ViewPager of these fragments (for example).

Comment: I have already created everything, Jokes are displaying but in one card view if i use   xyz = xxx.split("/");

Comment: Don't use `split()`. Use the code above to parse the json, add the jokes to a List, transform it to an array and pass it to the adapter

Comment: xyz = xxx.split(","); using this it gets splited according to , and gets displayed in different different card view  But not the the one joke at a time. I needed  every joke which is between " " in different different card view. I am facing problem in splitting string

Comment: if i use above code then it will parse that particular jokes only, it will be static,.API is generating different 10 different jokes every time.

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject allData  = reader.getJSONObject("data"); // change it to your key
JSONArray allJokes = allData.getJSONArray("value");
```

Now you can iterate this array.

```
String joke;
for(int i=0; i<allJokes.length(); i++){
    joke = allJokes.getJSONObject(i).getString("joke");
}
```

And remember to enclose it all in `JSONException`

**So your code will look like:**

```
try {
    JSONObject allData  = reader.getJSONObject("data"); // change it to your key
    JSONArray allJokes = allData.getJSONArray("value");

    String joke;
    for(int i=0; i<allJokes.length(); i++){
        joke = allJokes.getJSONObject(i).getString("joke"); 

        // do whatever you want with joke    
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: xyz = xxx.split("\"\"") when i use this all jokes are getting printed in one card view..

Comment: i need to print different joke in different card view through adaptor,,

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
try {
       jsonObject = new JSONObject("response");
       JSONArray value = jsonObject.getJSONArray("value");

       for (int i = 0; i < value.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject data = value.getJSONObject(i);
            Log.i("id", data.getString("id"));
            Log.i("joke", data.getString("joke"));
            JSONArray categories = data.getJSONArray("categories");
            for (int j = 0; j < categories.length(); j++) {
                 String str = categories.getString(i);
                 Log.e("categories", str);
            }
        }
} catch (JSONException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the Volley API instead of using Httpconnection in android.
Know Volley here: [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)